# Gap in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating a chart using JFreeChart, and I get the following behavior.

[image: JFreeChart StackedXYAreaChart]

Notice the gap between the light and dark shades of pink.

I was just plotting sample data over time, so I don't think it has anything to do with my data. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I am using a stacked XY area chart.

Here is the code to create my dataset:

```
double sample = 1.0;
TimeTableXYDataset dataset = new TimeTableXYDataset();
List<TimeSeries> timeSeriesList = timeSeriesCollection.getSeries();
for (TimeSeries t : timeSeriesList) {
  for (index = 0; index < t.getItemCount(); index++) {
    dataset.add(t.getTimePeriod(index), sample, t.getDescription());
  }
  sample++;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I was overwriting the plot renderer with itself.